# AJAX Handling Errors

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, error-handling

From my backend I wrote a POST api which returns a 403 error if a condition occurs. Together with the 403 error I am also passing a JSON response. In my front end I am using an AJAX request, however I can't seem to be able to read the JSON response when this error occurs. Are there ways to handle/capture the error and then read the JSON response as well ?

I was going to use the .then method however an error still props up without returning the JSON response.

Comment: Get the `responseText` from the jqXHR object provided to the `error`/`fail` handler function. Note that if it's JSON you'll need to parse it manually.

Comment: Just found out about it, thanks! :)